# How to save the values from a textbox and dropdown in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save the values entered in a textbox and also the one selected from a drop-down into localstorage. I tried the following code:

```
<table class="dynatable" id="my">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name1" onchange="saveSelectedValues();"></td>
        <td><select id="type" onchange="saveSelectedValues();"><option>Text</option><option>Paragraph</option><option>Dropdown</option></select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="Javascript:addRow()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my saveSelectedValues function is as below:

```
function saveSelectedValues(){
    var myName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var type = document.getElementById("type").value;

    localStorage.setItem("attributeName",myName);
    localStorage.setItem("attributeType",type); 
}
```

But the values are not getting saved in localstorage.

Comment: on which browser you are testing?

Comment: Does you browser support localstorage? http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine

```
saveSelectedValues = function(){
    var myName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var type = document.getElementById("type").value;

    localStorage.setItem("attributeName",myName);
    localStorage.setItem("attributeType",type); 
     alert(localStorage.getItem("attributeName"));
}
```

look for below jsfiddle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHmVP)

Make sure your browser is supporting html 5 local storage functionality and setting to allowed local storage.